# Iterate Nested JSON with Jquery and return matched index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I have a nested JSON object:

```
var library = {
    "Gold Rush": {
        "slides": ["Slide 1 Text","Slide 2 Text","Slide 3 Text","Slide 4 Text"],
        "bgs":["<img src='1.jpg' />","","<img src='2.jpg' />",""]
    },
    "California": {
        "slides": ["Slide 1 Text","Slide 2 Text","Slide 3 Text"],
        "bgs":["","<img src='3.jpg' />",""]
    }
}
```

How do I match the "slides" index to the "bgs" index for each item? 
I'm using jQuery. Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="shows">
    <ul>
        <li>Gold Rush</li>
        <li>California</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="items">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var lib = JSON.parse(library);

$('#shows li').bind('click', function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    var slides = (lib[title].slides);
    var bgs = (lib[title].bgs);
    $('#items ul').html('');
    $.each(slides, function(i){
        var bg = $(bgs).eq(i);  // The problem seems to be here?
        $('#items ul').append('<li><ul><li>'+this+'</li><li>'+bg+'</li></ul></li>');
    });
});
```

My hope is for the output for the show "California" to look like this:

```
<div id="items">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Slide 1 Text</li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Slide 2 Text</li>
                <li><img src='3.jpg' /></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Slide 3 Text</li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var bg = $(bgs).eq(i);
```

to this:

```
var bg = bgs[i];
```

...also, you should change this:

```
$('#items ul')
```

to this:

```
$('#items > ul')
```

...it uses the [`child-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)  so that you're not targeting the new `<ul>` elements you've already appended.

*(I guess the `>` isn't actually necessary in this case since you're clearing the content of `#items ul` on each click.)*

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uHKcd/1/

You could also cache the `#items > ul` element so you don't need to keep re-selecting it, especially in the `$.each()` loop.

Here's the finished code:

```
var items_ul = $('#items ul');

$('#shows li').bind('click', function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    var slides = (lib[title].slides);
    var bgs = (lib[title].bgs);
    items_ul.html('');
    $.each(slides, function(i){
        var bg = bgs[i];
        items_ul.append('<li><ul><li>'+this+'</li><li>'+bg+'</li></ul></li>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`bgs` is an array, you shouldn't wrap it in jquery, simply use it:

```
var bg = bgs[i];
```